# Text with Transparent Background infront of an image

Tags: html, css, image, hover

**HTML**

---

```
<article id="articlebottom">
    <div class="products">
        <div class="imgWrap">
            <img src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTA1uJ8WQ7fiJ2cbdoMph39XIJYQztt6FWoxfkk32gwnOz0qcmjyg" alt="candle" />
            <p class="imgDescription">Camphor</p>
        </div>
        <div class="imgWrap">
            <img src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTA1uJ8WQ7fiJ2cbdoMph39XIJYQztt6FWoxfkk32gwnOz0qcmjyg" alt="candle" />
            <p class="imgDescription">Camphor</p>
        </div>
        <div class="imgWrap">
            <img src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTA1uJ8WQ7fiJ2cbdoMph39XIJYQztt6FWoxfkk32gwnOz0qcmjyg" alt="candle" />
            <p class="imgDescription">Camphor</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
#articlebottom {

    width: 980px;
    height: 300px;          
}

.products
{
    width:980px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-left:20px;


} 
#articlebottom .imgWrap img {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:295px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    height:200px;
    border:5px solid #000;

}

#articlebottom .imgDescription {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top:35px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 250, 250, 0.2);
    color: #1b9bff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18pt;
    width:310px;
    height:50px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align:center;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 100;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    /*-webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.2s;*/
}
#articlebottom .imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
    visibility: visible;

}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2wJb/)

**What I'm having:**

1. I have three images.
2. The Text appears on the first image even when i hover on the second image..!

**What i need:**

1. When i hover on the image the appropriate text shoould appear over the image with a transparent background.

**Problem with my design:**

The text appears only on the first image even when i hover on the second image..!!

Comment: http://www.katieandemil.com/sql-server-check-if-record-exists-before-insert-using-t-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use position absolute make sure that the parent of that element has a relative position:

## [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z2wJb/2/)

```
*{/*reset*/
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#articlebottom {
    width: 980px;
    height: 300px;          
}

.products{
    width:980px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-left:20px;
} 
#articlebottom .imgWrap {
    width:295px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;/* set .imgWrap to relative to be able to use position absolute on childrens*/
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    border:5px solid #000;
}
#articlebottom .imgWrap img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#articlebottom .imgDescription {
    position: absolute;
    top:35px;
    left:0;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 250, 250, 0.2);
    color: #1b9bff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18pt;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align:center;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 100;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    /*-webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.2s;*/
}
#articlebottom .imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
    visibility: visible;

}
```

## [UPDATE: DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z2wJb/4/)

Comment: can you please make the transparent background appear in the whole image?

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/09/the-hr-contest-results-download-your-fresh-hr-line-now/

Answer (score 0):

I just Came up with @kougiland Solution, You need to set transparent background height to image height

**CSS**

```
  *{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#articlebottom {
    width: 980px;
    height: 300px;          
}

.products{
    width:980px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-left:20px;
} 
#articlebottom .imgWrap {
    width:295px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    background:black;
}
#articlebottom .imgWrap img {
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:5px;
    width:285px;
    height:190px;
}

#articlebottom .imgDescription {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 250, 250, 0.2);
    color: rgba(255, 250, 250, 0.2);
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18pt;
    line-height: 50px;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition:opacity 500ms ease-in-out, color 20ms ease-in-out,height 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#articlebottom .imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
    opacity: 1;
    height:100%;
    color: #1b9bff;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/x37rD/7/)

Comment: Mark answer for kougiland

Comment: +1 for not been scumbag Steve! here are some smooth updates to your      http://jsfiddle.net/x37rD/7/