# Text not disappearing properly

Tags: html, css

**CSS**

```
#articlebottom {
    width: 980px;
    height: 250px;          
}

.products{
    width:980px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-left:20px;
} 
#articlebottom .imgWrap {
    width:295px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    background:#333;
}
#articlebottom .imgWrap img {
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:5px;
    width:285px;
    height:190px;
}

#articlebottom .imgDescription1 {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 250, 250, 0.2);
    color: rgba(255, 250, 250, 0.2);
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18pt;
    line-height: 50px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition:opacity 500ms ease-in-out, color 20ms ease-in-out,height 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#articlebottom .imgWrap:hover .imgDescription1 {
    opacity: 1;
    height:200px;
    line-height:200px;
    color: #1b9bff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <article id="articlebottom">
                <div class="products">

                    <div class="imgWrap">
                        <a href="Products/Camphor.aspx"  target="_blank"><img src="Images/Camphor_b.JPG" alt="polaroid" />
                        <p class="imgDescription1">Camphor</p></a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
</article>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fP9xW/)**

**What I'm having:**

1. The Text appears on the center when i hover and going to top after hover

**What i need:**

1. When i hover on the image the appropriate text shoould appear on the center and also need to disappear  on center of the image itself

Comment: this ist the same question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582748/text-with-transparent-backgroud-infront-of-an-image/22582845#22582845

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k5UPV/6/

Comment: text-shadow: -5px -1px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/fP9xW/1/)

The crucial part is moving

```
    height:200px;
    line-height:200px;
    color: #1b9bff;
```

From:

`#articlebottom .imgWrap:hover .imgDescription1`

To:

`#articlebottom .imgDescription1`

Otherwise the position of the text is set to a default/inherited value and only set to centred on hover, hence why the hover state sees it jump.

Comment: It's good but i need that transparent needs to go up and down

Comment: @VigneshKumar Wouldn't it be better if the "overlay" slides in? At the moment the text just fades in before the "overlay" gets to it. Looks kinda odd.

Comment: @VigneshKumar Like this. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/fP9xW/3/) Or this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/fP9xW/4/) **Note:** the height is not correct for them as I just did it quickly.

Comment: @SW4 It's too good..If i want bottom to up means what should i do

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar I'd post a seperate question for your subsequent requirements in order for it to get more coverage from the community and to better help other users in future

Comment: @SW4 where can i get that